# run openconnect without sudo

Tags: sudo, non-root-user, openconnect

I want to start a VPN connection without needing to type in the password to the VPN connection or the password for sudo and without saving the password on my pc accessible to any normal users.

ATM I have a bash-script that is runnable and readable only by root which contains the VPN password so to startup the VPN I still need to use sudo to run it.

I compiled the bash-script so I can now let normal users run it without exposing the password to them (at least I think so, can it still get sniffed from traffic or something?).

But openconnect still needs sudo, can I somehow solve that?

Comment: what does "compiling" a bash script mean? No, basically every file that a user can execute they can also read. You're still saving the password on your PC accessible to every user.

Comment: But: if you set up a system-wide connection in NetworkManager, that will actually end up in a file not world-readable, so actually going the standard way as supported by your desktop environment would be the way to go. What's your desktop environment? Ubuntu running GNOME? Fedora?

Comment: Linux Mint with XFCE
Compiling meant creating a binary with shc which made a .x file
The VPN is for work, Ive sit it up through the networkmanager but it does not work, it does not even show an error but my IPv4 stays the same and is not in the network of my workplace. My ipv6 changes though.

Comment: There are some options for running openconnect as non-root user: https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html